# Override external css in TreeTable (scss)

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, treetable

I use TreeTable for display data in my React app (I use TypeScript with scss)
There is code

```
<div className='my-tree-table'>
  <TreeTable
    value={treeValue} ...
```

which is translated for such javascript.
[image]

My question is how to write my scss **my-tree-view** class for override **height** param in **cp-tree-table_viewport** which belongs to external TreeTable component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to override it with using css.
Overriding inline styles is possible only with `!important` keyword

in your case, this would be:

```
.my-tree-table {
   .cp_tree-table_viewport {
      height: 100px !important;
   }
}
```